# resize image using draggable button - React Native

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, components, resize

I search some package or css property that on click and drag will resize my Image.

for example: (black sqaure is the button)

[real size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9ePY.png)
[change size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atlUB.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a package specifically for this, at least not that I know of.

What I would do is use the package [react-rnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rnd) or any other similar package that has a resize functionality. You could use the resize functionality (disable the drag-and-drop) and lock the aspect ratio of the image for the resize onchange event.

I believe the package I mentioned has the option to lock the aspect ratio (`lockAspectRatioExtraHeight`), but if you decide to use another one, you could simply read the image's width & height, calculate the aspect ratio from there, and listen to the resize event to lock the aspect ratio yourself.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you ! I used and its awsome !